# Adjusting legend title position in ggplot object, R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, legend

In the following example I am using `factoextra` and `FactoMineR` to create a biplot. The plot has a colour bar and the title is technically centered in the middle, but it is in the middle of the colour bar and the tick numbers inclusive, making it look too low, particularly when I have another legend next to it.

```
library("factoextra")
library("FactoMineR")

data("decathlon2")
df <- decathlon2[1:23, 1:10]

res.pca <- PCA(df,  graph = FALSE)

p<-fviz_pca_var(res.pca, col.var="contrib", 
             gradient.cols = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
             repel = TRUE)+
  theme(legend.position='bottom')

p$labels$colour<-'Contribution to variance'
```

[image]

I would like to raise it, and I have tried using `+guides(colour=guide_legend(title.vjust = 0.5))`

```
p<-fviz_pca_var(res.pca, col.var="contrib", 
             gradient.cols = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
             repel = TRUE)+
  theme(legend.position='bottom')+
  guides(colour=guide_legend(title.vjust = 0.5))

p$labels$colour<-'Contribution to variance'
```

But this gets rid of the colour bar in exchange for letters. Can anyone help solve this? FYI the plot is a `ggplot` object. Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `guide_colourbar()` rather than `guide_legend()` when trying to modify it:

```
p <- fviz_pca_var(res.pca, col.var = "contrib", 
                gradient.cols = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
                repel = TRUE)+
    # You can use labs() to set labels
    labs(colour = "Contribution to variance") +
    guides(colour = guide_colourbar(title.vjust = 0.9)) +
    theme(legend.position = 'bottom')
print(p)
```

Comment: So simple! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `legend.title` parameter inside `theme()` to change adjust the position of the legend title:

```
theme(legend.position = "bottom",
      legend.title = element_text(vjust = 0.75)
      )
```